# How to set low memory to false?

Tags: python, data-visualization, google-colaboratory

I need to visualize this dataset. I first got an error saying that I had multiple dtypes, so I am trying to set `low_memory` to `False`. However I cannot find the right syntax.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import io

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

train_data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.csv'], 
low_memory=False))

num_rows = train_data.shape[0]


counter_nan = train_data.isnull().sum()
counter_without_nan = counter_nan[counter_nan == 0]
train_data = train_data[counter_without_nan.keys()]
train_data = train_data.drop({"Team", "DisplayName" , "GameClock" , 
"PossessionTeam" ,"OffensePersonnel" , "DefensePersonnel" , 
"PlayDirection" , "TimeHandoff" , "TimeSnap" , "PlayerHeight" , 
"PlayerBirthDate" , "PlayerCollegeName" , "Position" , "HomeTeamAbbr" , 
"VisitorTeamAbbr" , "Stadium" , "Location", "Turf"},axis = 1)

c = train_data.iloc[:,:-1].values
standard_scalar = StandardScaler()
c_std = standard_scalar.fit_transform(c)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state = 0)
c_test_2d = tsne.fit_transform(c_std)

markers = ('s', 'd', 'o', '^', 'v')
color_map = {0:'red', 1:'blue' ,2:'lightgreen',3:'purple', 4:'cyan'}
plt.figure()
for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(c_test_2d)):
    plt.scatter(x=c_test_2d[cl,0], y= c_test_2d[cl,1], c=color_map[idx], 
marker=markers[idx], label=cl)
plt.show()
```

I expect:

```py
train_data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.csv'], low_memory=False))
```

to set the `low_memory` to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

try changing below line

```
train_data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.csv'], low_memory=False))
```

to

```
train_data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.csv']), low_memory=False)
```

You were passing the `low_memory` argument to `io.BytesIO` instead of `pd.read_csv`